# Javascript: Create a buffer like object that collects input keystrokes then releases them one-by-one to a function at timed intervals

Tags: javascript, input, buffer, delay, timing

I am trying to create a buffer like object that collects all the keystrokes from an input field then passes them to a function one-by-one with a set timed delay between each.

For example, when using the `Google Maps/Places Autocomplete Service API`, every keystroke made in the input field fires the Autocomplete's request function, I have found that if too many keystrokes are made in a very short space of time, the Autocomplete request fails to return results. Therefore I would like to create some sort of buffer that collects all keystrokes, then one-by-one, at say a `200ms interval`, releases them to the Autocomplete function.

So input of 123 Fake St taking 700ms, then pass each character of the string to a function at 200ms intervals - 1 (200ms) 2 (200ms) 3 (200ms) F (200ms) A ... ect.

I have no solid ideas of how to write such at thing at present so cannot post code, but I would have thought it would be something along the lines of

```
On key press:

    if( (lastRequestTime - 200) > curTime )
        send input to function
```

However this is clearly far from complete. Has anyone any thoughts on how this might be achieved?

Comment: Why don't you simply have a setTimeout that you reset on every keystroke? Then once it expires, you know that no key was pressed for whatever interval you specified. That would be a good time to fire/show the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an onkeydown event on the input, (like you've shown). Or in some browsers you might need to place the event on the body and just wait for a focus event on the element. The one main bit of wisdom I can give is for the timing pattern. You should set up a queue object that takes in a key and handles sending them. Basically it should have a bool called "ready" set to true on creation, then whenever it gets a new key it will send it right away if it's ready. But if it's not, it will add it to the queue, (usually an array). Whenever you have it send a key just have it set a timeout that will fire another send (on the next key on the queue) if one's there or just set ready to true.

Warning: not technically valid javascript. Mostly an example.

```
takeKey( key )
{
  if ( this.ready )
    this.sendIt( key );
  else
    this.queue.push( key );
}

sendIt ( key )
{
  this.ready = false;
  send( key );
  timeout(function () {
    this.readyUp();    
  }, time);
}

readyUp ()
{
  ready = true;
  if (this.queue.length > 0)
    this.sendIt( this.queue.shift() );
}
```

That should handle up on your timing. The rest is just basic dom coding.

P.S. check for something called throttle is the docs of your autocomplete widget. The solution might be baked right in.